# Avoid Vue warn when using custom tags

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, tags

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to use custom tags like this:

`<material-button>Ok</material-button>`

It's not a real component, just semantic HTML with a specific CSS. However, I'm getting this Vuew error:

```
 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <material-button> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in
```

Can I avoid this error without having to create and register `<material-button>` as a component?

Note: everything works perfectly is just that [Vue warn] that pops up in the console all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-pre` attribute on your component

```html
<material-button v-pre> </material-button>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre

or you can use `ignoredElements`

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
    "material-button"
]
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements

Comment: Awesome Owl. Finally my HTML is more meaningful with the custom tags and I can avoid long dividities with so many classes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable warnings on a per component basis as per [Linus_Borg](https://twitter.com/Linus_Borg/status/1040004906520899589)

However you can use [Vue.config.silent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#silent) to suppress all warnings

Answer (score 0):

you can check the solution here:
[Vue warn Failed to resolve component: ion-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620525/vue-warn-failed-to-resolve-component-ion-icon)

if you want tot past and pass, update `vue.config.js` like

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          ...options.compilerOptions,
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('material-')
        }
        return options
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in my webpack config, by applying these options to the vue-loader:

```
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: "vue-loader",
    options: {
      cacheBusting: false, // true by default (:
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement:  (tag) => tag === "lottie-player",
      },
    },
  },
```

By doing this I don't get any warnings when using

```
<lottie-player></lottie-player>
```

in my components.

My setup is:

```
"vue": "^3.2.31",
"vue-loader": "^16.2.0",
"webpack": "^5.53.0",
```