# Vue warn Failed to resolve component: ion-icon

Tags: vue.js, ionicons

Following the usage at https://ionicons.com/usage, the `ion-icon` displays but I get this warning:

```
Failed to resolve component: ion-icon
```

My steps were:

- I used `@vue/cli@4.5.11` to create a new app (`vue create projectname`)
- added `<ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>` to `HelloWorld.vue`
- added `<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>` to public/index.html

I've tried `app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('ion')` which created another warning saying the option is only respected when using the runtime compiler, but I was able to suppress it by adding a `vue.config.js` with `module.exports = {runtimeCompiler: true}`. No effect on the `ion-icon` warning. This might be linked to needing to use a custom vue-loader but is there an easy way to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full warning from using `app.config.isCustomElement` provides a useful clue:

> The `isCustomElement` config option is only respected when using the runtime compiler. If you are using the runtime-only build, `isCustomElement` must be passed to `@vue/compiler-dom` in the build setup instead- for example, via the `compilerOptions` option in vue-loader: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#compileroptions.

You could [modify `vue-loader`'s `compilerOptions` in `vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) to configure `isCustomElement`:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          ...options.compilerOptions,
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('ion-')
        }
        return options
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: For vite 2 this is done in vite.config.js

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/153#issuecomment-775256229

Comment: For me the problem was that I was attempting to import the external component using my component's `setup` method.  However, this doesn't work for components; they **must** be imported using the `components` member variable