# Testing vue with a web component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, web-component, vue-test-utils

My application is using astrouxds web components and I am getting a warning in my tests that I would like to fix. I'm also not sure how to assert on a value in the web component.

```
  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
    [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <rux-toggle> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
    
    found in
    
    ---> <App>
           <Root>
```

I have setup an example application [here](https://github.com/moaxcp/vue-astro/tree/questions/68532392). It uses `rux-toggle` as an example.

The application has a simple template and script in a `.vue` file.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <rux-toggle
        id="app-toggle"
        :checked="toggle"
        @click.prevent="toggle = !toggle"></rux-toggle> {{ toggle }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed: {
    toggle: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.toggle
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('setToggle', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The test uses `mount` to create a wrapper and test that the web component is checked.

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {createLocalVue, mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import storeConfig from '@/store'
import App from '@/App'

describe("App", () => {
  let localVue;
  let store;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    store = new Vuex.Store(storeConfig);
    wrapper = mount(App, {store, localVue});
  });

  it("test toggle default", () => {
    const result = wrapper.find('#app-toggle').checked;
    expect(result).toEqual(true);
  })
})
```

The test fails with:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: true
Received: undefined
```

I'm not exactly sure how to get the `checked` value of the web component to do the assertion correctly.

## Things I have tried

1. Switched from shallowMount to mount
2. Register globally using Vue.component(rux-toggle, RuxToggle)
3. Added `Vue.config.productionTip = false` to jest setup

Comment: Why exactly are you importing the `RuxToggle` component in your main.js file and not in the App.vue file and add it properly to the components property of your App.vue component?

Comment: If you want to register it globally you should add `Vue.component('rux-toggle', RuxToggle)` to the main.js file. Else it makes no sense to import the component like that and ignore that eslint tells you you're doing something fishy :D

Comment: I'm not 100% sure from what I saw the imported file has `customElements.define('rux-toggle', RuxToggle);` at the bottom. I thought maybe this should be global rather than in each component that uses it.

Comment: Registering it globally causes a different error in the browser. `Class constructor RuxToggle cannot be invoked without 'new'"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>`

Comment: Yeah no I'm just dumb, I actually thought the rux thing is a "normal" component but after considering your question it's obviously a web component you want to use :D Sorry for that.
There is another answer to this question that I believe might solve your issue. It's right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912836/avoid-vue-warn-when-using-custom-tags)

Comment: There aren't any issues when the app runs. I don't see the warning in the browser. It is only happening in tests where I have to assert on the component.

Comment: You might be able to avoid those by adding a setup file for jest (you're using jest I assume?)
So add a `index.js` or `index.ts` file to your test directory or wherver.
In it you'll put `Vue.config.productionTip = false;`.
Then add `setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/tests/index.ts"]` to your jest.config.js file.

Comment: I tried that and the warnings still show. I also added to the question that the test is actually failing. I'm not sure how to get the `checked` value out of the web component.

Comment: Mh... that sucks.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478484/how-to-test-custom-web-component-with-jest) can provide a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rux-toggle` component is only registered in `main.js`, leading to the warnings/errors you observed.

*Regarding your attempts:*

> 1. Switched from shallowMount to mount

Custom elements must be explicitly registered by your own code, and `mount` isn't going to do that for you.

> 2. Register globally using Vue.component(rux-toggle, RuxToggle)

`RuxToggle` from `@astrouxds/rux-toggle` is a [`LitElement`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/defining/), which does not meet the requirements of a *Vue component definition* that [`Vue.component()` expects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component).

> 3. Added `Vue.config.productionTip = false` to jest setup

That merely disables a browser console warning about using the developent build in production, and has nothing to do with custom elements or component registration. Perhaps you meant to use [`Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['rux-toggle']`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements), which would mute the warning about unknown custom elements (this is actually unnecessary in unit tests), but it does not register the custom element.

### Solution

To properly use `rux-toggle` in your tests:

1. Create a Jest setup file that registers `rux-toggle`. Importing it is enough to do that, as the custom element registration happens as a side effect.

   ```js
   // tests/jest.setup.js
   import '@astrouxds/rux-toggle'
   ```
2. Configure Jest to use the setup file:

   ```js
   // jest.config.js
   module.exports = {
     setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/tests/jest.setup.js'],
   }
   ```
3. Configure Jest to transpile `@astrouxds/rux-toggle`:

   ```js
   // jest.config.js
   module.exports = {
     transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules//(?!@astrouxds/rux-toggle)'],
   }
   ```
4. Your project uses `jest` 24.9.0, which depends on `jsdom` 15, which does not support Custom Elements. To enable Custom Elements in this version of Jest, install [`jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen):

   ```bash
   npm install -D jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen
   ```
5. Configure Jest to use that test environment:

   ```js
   // jest.config.js
   module.exports = {
     testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen',
   }
   ```
6. Update your test to read the `checked` attribute with [`attributes('checked')`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#attributes), and verify the value is `"true"` (attributes are string values):

   ```js
   it("test toggle default", () => {
     const result = wrapper.find('#app-toggle').attributes('checked');
     expect(result).toEqual('true');
   })
   ```

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/moaxcp/vue-astro/pull/1)

Comment: Thanks! This all worked. My team can now write tests!